# Any ideas for protecting a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, stack-overflow

I have a question.

Do any of you have an idea how I can use protecting page from direct url example. You can edit some message from guestbook [here](http://yoururlhere/administration/edit.aspx)
but it needs to be protected.

I have already but if you enter it directly into your address bar it gives you access. That's bad. BTW I am learning `ASP.NET`

this is my code.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Stefan"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Username],[Password] from Admin where [Username] = @Username and [Password] = @Password", con))
        {
            string Username = (textUsername.Text.Length > 0) ? textUsername.Text : null;
            string Password = (TextPassword.Text.Length > 0) ? TextPassword.Text : null;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textUsername.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextPassword.Text;

            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                    if (Page.IsValid)
                    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into forms based authentication, that will hold the answers to this problem. If you setup a new MVC / Webform project in VS2010 you will find a preconfigured example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  First, you should be using the ASP.NET Membership and Roles system to control access to pages that you do not want unauthorized users to access.

Try here to start with:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/07/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-Roles-Tutorial-Series.aspx

Secondly, if you want to prevent users from arriving at a page directly (even if they're authorized to access the page normally) then you need to add a test of some sort, such as setting a session variable and checking for it in the OnLoad of the page you need to test.